# CSS|Установка изображения поверх

Tags: html, css

Всем привет!
Имеется HTML код:

```
<div class="opacity-img">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Evgeniy Sobaka</h1>
        <div class="imgRounded">
          <img class="personPhoto" src="img/iAM.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

К нему подключен CSS:

```
.imgRounded {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 999999 !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.personPhoto {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 999999 !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.opacity-img {
  background-image: url(img/asphalt.jpg);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 200px;
  border-radius: 24px;
}

.container {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: rgb(212, 121, 2);
  border-radius: 24px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px rgba(28, 29, 28, 0.9);
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Как избежать наложение прозрачности и эффекта от картинки на изображении?
Сейчас получается вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может просто не делать фото прозрачным?

Comment: У вас `.container` `opacity: 0.4;` , а в контейнере находится картинка: следовательно и картинка прозрачная. Уберите там opacity, и всё

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.opacity-img {
  background-image: url(img/asphalt.jpg);
  margin: 200px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  position: relative;
}

.opacity {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 24px;
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: -1;
}

.container {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: rgba(212, 121, 2, 0.4);
  border-radius: 24px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px rgba(28, 29, 28, 0.9);
  z-index: 1;
}

.personPhoto {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="opacity-img">
  <div class="opacity"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Evgeniy Sobaka</h1>
    <div class="imgRounded">
      <img class="personPhoto" src="img/iAM.png" alt="photo" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Можно добавить и стилизовать отдельный див.

Answer (score 0):

Использова RGBA, указал в нем прозрачность для цвета:

```
  .personPhoto {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}

.opacity-img {
  background-image: url(img/asphalt.jpg);
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 200px;
  border-radius: 24px;
}

.container {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: rgba(212, 121, 2, 0.4);
  border-radius: 24px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px rgba(28, 29, 28, 0.9);
}
```